# How can I search the text of a list of webpages and return which pages contain that text?

Tags: php, html

What I am aiming to do is search several HTML webpages for a specific string. Then, take the pages that contain that string and echo them back.

Say, take all the webpages on "example.com/php" and search for "foobar".
What should happen is there should be a list echoed that lists the URLs that contained "foobar".

I'm using a simple HTML form and using POST to a PHP page, but I have not found a method to go through the webpages quickly and return a list.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the web page source. Then use the search function or regular expression to check if page contains the text you want.